# Day and time range picker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Could anyone recommend me a good time day (only the name - ex:Monday) and time range picker..

I already tried http://pttimeselect.sourceforge.net/example/index.html and http://haineault.com/media/jquery/ui-timepickr/page/
but they don't have day selection..

anyone knows another one?

Comment: I tried also http://www.ama3.com/anytime/

Comment: Good as in? Reliable/pretty/tough?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I mean just that do the job.. the ones I tried don't have a day picker..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I seriously spent hours looking for something similar for our site [ParkMe.com](http://parkme.com).  It seems with all the implementations someone out there would have created one.

When I couldn't find anything, I spent the weekend writing my own.  Here's what I came up with.

http://keithhackbarth.github.io/jquery-datetime-picker/

https://github.com/keithhackbarth/jquery-datetime-picker

Not trying to self plug.. just think I came up with a half decent solution.

Answer (score 6):

I really like this one: http://ghusse.github.com/jQRangeSlider/

It's highly customizable. Supports Dates, Integers and has a lot of options to fit it to your special needs.